# Увеличивается ID в метаданных (update_post_meta) php

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

Добавляю данные при помощи `update_post_meta()` (php).
Данные успешно добавляются в базу. НО в базе вижу такую картину:

```
"meta_data":[{"id":3792,"key":"_kay1","value":"2"},{"id":3793,"key":"_kay2","value":"6,6"}
```

Приписывается к каждому ключу id и он увеличивается, причем продолжает увеличиваться в последующих постах.

Откуда он берется там?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метаданные в WordPress хранятся в отдельной таблице wp_post_meta. У каждой записи этой таблицы есть свой id (автоинкремент), поле ключа, поле значения и поле id поста, к которому относится эта мета-запись.

В целом, вам все это знать не нужно, и заглядывать в базу - тоже.

Используйте функцию WordPress get_post_meta() для получения метаданных конкретного поста.

Comment: Увы но мне нужно))), я просто думал что я делаю что-то не так ,поэтому он появляется перед ключом. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

`update_post_meta` - это не стандартная функция `PHP`, эта функция вашего движка `WordPress` соответственно если хотите разобраться, надо [смотреть документацию (ссылка)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/).

P.S. Добавлю: скорее всего ваш `id` - это просто авто-инкремент, по нему система понимает было-ли изменено поле, и приблизительно когда (в какой последовательности) поля изменялись.

Comment: Я читал но мои познания в php слишком малы, что-бы разобраться в этом(